# How to do recursion on typeorm relations

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

category.ts

```
@Entity('categoryenter code here')
export class Category{
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'int' })
  id: Category;

  @OneToMany(() => Category, category => category.category,{eager:true})
  categoryList: Category[];

  @ManyToOne(() => Category, (category) => category.categoryList)
  category: Category;
}
```

The Category entity is above(mysql).
I want to find a category with all it's children like this

```
await categoryRepo.findOne({
  where:{ id: 1 },
  relations:['categoryList']
})
```

But I got an error `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

What am I suppose to do

Answer (score 15):

Actually, as I see, you are trying to make a **tree data structure**. TypeORM has some decorators for that. Here is an example:

```js
import {
  Entity, BaseEntity, Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Tree,
  TreeParent, TreeChildren
} from 'typeorm';

@Tree('materialized-path')
@Entity({ name: 'Menu' })
export class Category extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'int' })
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 50 })
  text: string;

  // Check bellow
  @TreeParent()
  parent: Category;

  @TreeChildren()
  children: Category[];
}
```

The decorator `@Tree()` is used to tell to TypeORM that every Instance has self references for itself. Every item should have one parent, and should have several children. The ancestors and descendant can be setted with the decorators `@TreeParent()` and `@TreeChildren()` respectively. Check the [documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/tree-entities) for more details about the different modes available for `@Tree()` decorator.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `eager` loading, each `Category` object is trying to load all its children eligible for `categoryList`. And since `categoryList` is also a list of `Category` entities, all it's children are also trying to load `categoryList` of their own. And this goes on and on until the stack is overflowed.

Remove `eager` loading from `Category` entity:

```js
@Entity('categoryenter code here')
export class Category{
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'int' })
  id: Category;

  @OneToMany(() => Category, category => category.category)
  categoryList: Category[];

  @ManyToOne(() => Category, (category) => category.categoryList)
  category: Category;
}
```